# RxSwift - How to reflect the number of item's count to TableView

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift. This is quite tricky.

I'm creating like ToDoList that views which are tableView and add-item view are separated by TabBarController.
I have successfully displayed the list array and added a new item into tableView.

I also wanted to display the number of array's count and favourite count in the view that has tableView so that I have displayed it by throwing a value with `.just`.

**But displaying a value based on the result of the array displayed by SearchBar, the value is not reflected as I expected.**

In MainViewModel, I made sure if I could get the number of array's count properly by `print`, but apparently the value was fine. 
It is just not reflected in the View.

// Model

```swift
struct Item: Codable {
    var name = String()
    var detail = String()
    var tag = String()
    var memo = String()
    var fav = Bool()
    var cellNo = Int()

    init(name: String, detail: String, tag: String, memo: String, fav: Bool, celllNo: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.detail = detail
        self.tag = tag
        self.memo = memo
        self.fav = fav
        self.cellNo = celllNo
    }

    init() {
        self.init(
            name: "Apple",
            detail: "ringo",
            tag: "noun",
            memo: "",
            fav: false,
            celllNo: 0
        )
    }
}




struct SectionModel: Codable {
    var list: [Item]
}
extension SectionModel: SectionModelType {
    var items: [Item] {
        return list
    }

    init(original: SectionModel, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.list = items
    }

}
```

Singleton share class

```swift
final class Sharing {

    static let shared = Sharing()

    var items: [Item] = [Item()]

    var list: [SectionModel] = [SectionModel(list: [Item()])] {
        didSet {
            UserDefault.shared.saveList(list: list)
        }
    }

    let listItems = BehaviorRelay<[SectionModel]>(value: [])

}

extension Sharing {
    func calcFavCount(array: [Item]) -> Int {
        var count = 0
        if array.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...array.count - 1 {
                if array[i].fav {
                    count += 1
                }
            }
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

// MainTabViewController

```swift
class MainTabViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var listTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private lazy var viewModel = MainTabViewModel(
        searchTextObservable: searchTextObservable
    )

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private var dataSource: RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableViewDataSource()
        tableViewSetup()
        listDetailSetup()
    }

    // create Observable searchBar.text to pass to ViewModel
    var searchTextObservable: Observable<String> {

        let debounceValue = 200

        // observable to get the incremental search text
        let incrementalTextObservable = rx
            .methodInvoked(#selector(UISearchBarDelegate.searchBar(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)))
            .debounce(.milliseconds(debounceValue), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .flatMap { [unowned self] _ in Observable.just(self.searchBar.text ?? "") }

        // observable to get the text when the clear button or enter are tapped
        let textObservable = searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable()

        // merge these two above
        let searchTextObservable = Observable.merge(incrementalTextObservable, textObservable)
            .skip(1)
            .debounce(.milliseconds(debounceValue), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .distinctUntilChanged()

        return searchTextObservable
    }

    func setupTableViewDataSource() {
        dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel>(configureCell: {(_, tableView, indexPath, item) in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! ListCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.configure(item: item)
            return cell
        })
    }

    func tableViewSetup() {

        tableView.rx.itemDeleted
            .subscribe {
                print("delete")
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.dispItems.asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    func listDetailSetup() {

        viewModel.itemCountObservable
            .bind(to: itemCountLabel.rx.text)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.favCountObservable
            .bind(to: favCountLabel.rx.text)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

MainTabViewModel

```swift
final class MainTabViewModel {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let userDefault: UserDefaultManager
    var dispItems = BehaviorRelay<[SectionModel]>(value: [])
    private let shared = Sharing.shared

//    lazy var itemCount = shared.list[0].list.count
//    lazy var favCount = shared.calcFavCount

    var itemCountObservable: Observable<String>
    var favCountObservable: Observable<String>

    init(searchTextObservable: Observable<String>,
         userDefault: UserDefaultManager = UserDefault()) {

        self.userDefault = userDefault

        let initialValue = shared.list
        shared.listItems.accept(initialValue)
        dispItems = shared.listItems

       // this part is to display the initil number -> success
        var itemCount = shared.list[0].list.count
        itemCountObservable = .just(itemCount.description + " items")

        var favCount = shared.calcFavCount(array: shared.list[0].list)
        favCountObservable = .just(favCount.description)


        // this part is based on the searching result -> failure
        searchTextObservable.subscribe(onNext: { text in
            if text.isEmpty {
                let initialValue = self.shared.list
                self.shared.listItems.accept(initialValue)
                self.dispItems = self.shared.listItems
            }else{
                let filteredItems: [Item] = self.shared.list[0].list.filter {
                    $0.name.contains(text)
                }
                let filteredList = [SectionModel(list: filteredItems)]
                self.shared.listItems.accept(filteredList)
                self.dispItems = self.shared.listItems

                itemCount = filteredItems.count
                self.itemCountObservable = .just(itemCount.description + " items")
                favCount = self.shared.calcFavCount(array: filteredItems)
                self.favCountObservable = .just(favCount.description)

                print("\(itemCount) items") // the ideal number is in but not shown in the view
            }
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }

}
```

I removed unnecessary code but I mostly pasted a whole code for your understanding.

Hope you could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue anyway; the value was reflected.

the issue was that `itemCountObservable` was declared as `observable` and `.just` was used.

How `.just` works is to throw `onNext` once and it is completed, which means the change I did in `searchTextObservable.subscribe(onNext~` is unacceptable.

So I shifted the `itemCountObservable: Observable<String>` to `BehaviorRelay<String>`that only `onNext` is thrown and not completed, then it works.

My understanding of this issue is that `itemCountObservable: Observable<String>` stopped throwing a value due to `.just` as I've written above.

Am I correct??

If you're familiar with the difference between `Observable` and `BehaviorRelay`, it would be appreciated if you could tell me.

Thanks.